# Riddle Poem: "Within me you will find..."

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Who or what is this poem referring to?

> Within me you will find
>   One of like heart and mind.
>   As well as an entity
>   With inverted geography.
>
> While I represent symmetry
>   Mirrors can show another identity.
>   But there will always be twins
>   Who generate many grins.

Hints:

> The first 4 lines and last 4 lines should be interpreted differently.  Also, avigrail's [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6122/riddle-poem-within-me-you-will-find#comment19706_6122) about boobs is somewhat related to the answer.

Comment: I think a nice answer would be "boobs" ;)

Comment: @avigrail You might be closer than you realize. ;)

Comment: By your hint, does it mean that the first 4 lines and the last 4 lines represent different things?

Comment: @pacoverflow - A few answers are still awaiting feedback! :-) Also [things are heating up on meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/are-puzzles-and-riddles-welcome) - join in if you want to keep on riddling here!

Comment: Well, I feel like the intended answer fits worse than almost all of the suggested ones! That's riddling :p

Comment: @avigrail Yeah this one could have been better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is:

> A palindrome or a palindromic phrase

Within me you will find
One of like heart and mind.

> Within it is the effort of a thinker like the ones at Puzzling.SE

As well as an entity
With inverted geography.

> The entity with an inverted geography is the palindrome, as it reads the same in both directions.

While I represent symmetry
Mirrors can show another identity.

> Palindromes are symmetrical, but a mirroring the first half of the palindrome will not produce the same thing visually.

But there will always be twins
Who generate many grins.

> Palindromic phrases or sentences are not so hard to construct, and usually one makes up the first half and tries to mirror it with the second half and spaces. Most such sentences are usually quite funny (like  *taco cat* or *evil olive*) or have some weird meaning. A short [list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Palindromic_phrases#English).

Comment: +1, this is the answer I'm looking for.  I'll post more comments later, as many of my clue explanations are different from yours.

Comment: I posted [an answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6188/4450) with my explanations for the clues.

Answer (score 8):

### My answer

> Lungs

Within me you will find
One of like heart and mind.

> representations of being within something that is like the heart and mind (brain) such as an organ

As well as an entity
With inverted geography.

> many bacterial entities reside to create these. Inverted geography as the region it has when rested is inverted when its at full capacity. (vice-versa)

While I represent symmetry
Mirrors can show another identity.

> two lungs working in sync are symmetrical, mirrors as in reflections, reflect the user so smokers or people with ailments will show a different set of lungs. Also different DNA reflect different sizes and what not.

But there will always be twins
Who generate many grins.

> two lungs working in sync to generate oxygen to form lots of malicious/happy grins

Comment: @pacoverflow least I won't starve tonight :) thank you

Answer (score 6):

Within **me** you will find

*One of* like "h**e**art" and "**m**ind".

As well as an entity

With inverted geography:

> invert(m) = w

While I represent symmetry

**Mirrors** can show another identity.

But there will always be twins - twins: two letters

Who generate many grins.

> when we mirror "me" correctly there will be "aw" which is the sound of grinning people I suppose :D

Comment: Right up your street when there are mirrors involved :)

Answer (score 5):

Is this a

> Joker card?

Within me you will find
One of like heart and mind.

> A Joker card contains a depiction of a joker.

As well as an entity
With inverted geography.

> The joker card usually contains the word "joker" twice, one is inverted.

While I represent symmetry
Mirrors can show another identity.

> The card maintains rotational symmetry with respect to the word "joker", but does not remain the same under mirroring

But there will always be twins
Who generate many grins.

> There are two joker cards in a deck, and jokers generate many grins.

Comment: Every card holds a picture twice. So there are 2 pictures of a joker in addition to the word "joker".

Answer (score 5):

> A pregnant woman/embryo?

*Within me you will find 

One of like heart and mind. 

As well as an entity 

With inverted geography.*

> Foetuses are upside down inside the mother's womb.

*While I represent symmetry 

Mirrors can show another identity. 

But there will always be twins 

Who generate many grins.*

> Literally twins; they would generate many grins in the proud parents.

Avigrail's 'boobs' comment also fits into this.

Comment: +1, this is pretty good. But a pregnant woman won't always have twins.

Comment: @pacoverflow - Is the first part right? I might be able to reinterpret the second...

Answer (score 4):

My answer is:

> the human body

Within me you will find
One of like heart and mind...

As well as an entity
With inverted geography.

> Inverted geometry makes me think of something concave like a hole maybe. We have two inverted geometries worth mentioning I guess (mouth and a**hole). Since there is something about lips near the end I assume it is your *mouth* (providing we are talking about unisex here).

While I represent symmetry
Mirrors can show another identity.

> Bodies represent symmetry because every thing is there twice (besides inner organs) but as soon as we mirror each half independently it looks different after all (new identity).

But there will always be twins
Who generate many grins.

> The lips of your mouth generate grins (female body would have been more fun).

Comment: Can you explain more about how a mouth fits the inverted geography, and what the second one would be?  Also, this answer goes down the wrong path from my hint.

Answer (score 4):

> Within me you will find
> One of like heart and mind.
> As well as an entity
> With inverted geography.
>
> While I represent symmetry
> Mirrors can show another identity.
> But there will always be twins
> Who generate many grins.

The first 4 lines and last 4 lines should be interpreted differently.

---

Answer:

> The Heart.

Within *me* you will find
One of like heart and mind.

> Literally, something I will find in a word (me is the poem, assumed). And, literally, to select one of: like, *heart*, and mind.

As well as an *entity*
With *inverted* geography.

> Another key phrase (a command to invert something)

While I represent symmetry

> What represents symmetry? A mirror, but it can't be, for mirrors show another identity (below). A lake can do this, so can a pond, a bucket, a pool... etc. These literally represent symmetry, but *the heart* is a deeper represenetation of symmetry, that of emotional symmetry.

Mirrors can show another *identity*

> If we remove *entity* from *identity* we are left with *id*, and, when reversed, is *di*.

But there will always be *twins*

> *di* is a prefix for *two*, and twins are in *twos*.

Who generate many grins.

> The heart has two chambers, left and right. It is also responsible for (in a non-anatomical sense; figuratively) generating emotions.

Comment: +1 I like what you did with the first 2 lines. The 6th line seems interpreted the same way as the first 4 lines though. Also how do boobs fit into this?

Comment: @pacoverflow Well, the b--bs (sorry, I don't like the word terribly) are a source of desire, which is (figuratively) from the heart.

Answer (score 3):

Another answer:

> 3

Within me you will find
One of like heart and mind.

> *Within "me" you will find*
> *"1", of like heart and mind.*
>
> This means you are to look in the word "me" for something that is like "1", in other words a number.

As well as an entity
With inverted geography.

> This is the cue that the number is not right side up.  In this case, take m and rotate it to become 3.

While I represent symmetry
Mirrors can show another identity.

> 3 is symmetric, but put a mirror in the middle and it becomes 8.

But there will always be twins
Who generate many grins.

> :3
> The twins represent the colon, which when added, form the cat face smiley :3
>
> The heart in the previous passage can now be interpreted as <3

Comment: +1, but can you clarify what that colon in front of the 3 means?

Comment: I thought it was obvious...

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that until now...

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations to dmg for getting the [intended answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6173/4450)!

Here are my explanations for the clues.

The first 4 lines are about the word "palindrome" itself.

> Within me you will find One of like heart and mind.

A friend is a person of like heart and mind.  Pal is a synonym for friend, and "pal" is a substring of palindrome.  (I thought about using a clue for "palin" instead - as in Sarah Palin - but I thought that would be too U.S.-centric.)

> As well as an entity With inverted geography.

Countries have cities within them, but there is one example of a city (Rome) having a country (Vatican City) within it.  "Rome" is a substring of palindrome.

The last 4 lines are about the meaning of the word palindrome.

> While I represent symmetry

A palindrome by definition has symmetry.

> Mirrors can show another identity.

If you hold a word up to a mirror, it will not look the same, and may form a different word.  For example, the palindrome "bib" turns into "did" in a mirror.

> But there will always be twins

The first letter of a palindrome is twins with the last letter.  The second letter is twins with the second-to-last letter, and so on.

> Who generate many grins.

Many people think palindromes are fun!

Finally, the singular form of "boobs" is a palindrome.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's eyes. One can see themselves in someone else's eyes by reflection but they are reflections and hence laterally inverted but still represent symmetry. Twins because they are a pair. Grins because we can see many funny things with our eyes.